# Tomcat not getting stopped completely

Tags: windows, tomcat, memory, memory-leaks, windows-server

I'm unable to stop my Tomcat service on a Windows server; it is showing stopping. I had to manually kill the process from task scheduler. How to resolve this issue?

I'm getting the below errors in the catalina log

```
10-Dec-2023 04:33:17.744 INFO [Thread-2881] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
10-Dec-2023 04:33:18.708 INFO [Thread-2881] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
10-Dec-2023 04:33:19.083 INFO [Thread-2881] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
10-Dec-2023 04:33:19.130 INFO [Thread-2881] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
10-Dec-2023 04:33:25.896 INFO [Thread-2881] com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.destroy WSSERVLET15: JAX-WS servlet destroyed
10-Dec-2023 04:33:26.849 INFO [Thread-2881] com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextDestroyed WSSERVLET13: JAX-WS context listener destroyed
10-Dec-2023 04:33:27.036 WARNING [Thread-2881] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [espaceperso] appears to have started a thread named [File Watcher] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.2-redhat/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 com.documentum.fc.common.DfFileWatcher.run(DfFileWatcher.java:58)
10-Dec-2023 04:33:27.036 WARNING [Thread-2881] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [espaceperso] appears to have started a thread named [SessionDestroyer-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.2-redhat/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 com.adecco.edoc.core.session.SessionDestroyer.run(SessionDestroyer.java:44)
10-Dec-2023 04:33:27.036 WARNING [Thread-2881] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [espaceperso] appears to have started a thread named [SessionDestroyer-1401] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.2-redhat/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 com.adecco.edoc.core.session.SessionDestroyer.run(SessionDestroyer.java:44)
10-Dec-2023 04:33:27.036 WARNING [Thread-2881] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [espaceperso] appears to have started a thread named [SessionDestroyer-1898] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.2-redhat/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 com.adecco.edoc.core.session.SessionDestroyer.run(SessionDestroyer.java:44)
10-Dec-2023 04:33:27.036 WARNING [Thread-2881] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [espaceperso] appears to have started a thread named [SessionDestroyer-2025] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.2-redhat/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 com.adecco.edoc.core.session.SessionDestroyer.run(SessionDestroyer.java:44)
10-Dec-2023 04:33:27.036 WARNING [Thread-2881] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [espaceperso] appears to have started a thread named [SessionDestroyer-2012] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.2-redhat/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

These messages you are seeing are from Tomcat's leak-detection system. They indicate that your application (or a library you are using) has created threads that will continue to run after the application has stopped.

The proper solution is to ensure that your application stops these threads, usually by registering a `ServletContextListener` to clean things up when the context is being "destroyed" (application shut-down).

You may find that some libraries ship with listeners and/or "shut down the library" commands. You should arrange for those to be run on application shut-down.

There is not really any way for Tomcat to do this for you, you *must* do it yourself.